# Array.find() gives error "TypeError: theArray.find(...) is undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm getting `TypeError: theArray.find(...) is undefined` from a code that is in essence similar to this:

```
if (!Array.isArray(theArray)) console.error("WARNING! theArray is not an array: ", theArray);
console.log(theArray.find((element) => element).someProperty);
```

I'm not getting the error message *WARNING! theArray is not an array*, but I'm getting the error *theArray.find(...) is undefined*

The error message does not say that *theArray* is undefined, this is an error message that I would except when theArray is not of type array.

Inside the array function there would be a more complex logic, but I simlified it to focus on the Array.find() problem.
The variable `theArray` is an array of complex objects, with a lot of properties.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve]

Comment: Two times voted to close because of debugging details - without comment. What needs to be debugged?

Comment: most likely the problem is related to `someProperty`. I still haven't solved my own problem, but it seems that without `someProperty` it would work, so this will be a problem  with properties and not Array.find(). I will write down the solution when I find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array.find will return `undefined` when it does not find a result.

The error message means that `find()` function returned undefined, then `someProperty` can not be found on `undefined`.

Example for clarification:

```
let testArray = [{a: 3}, {a: 4}, {a: 5}];
let notArray = 5;
```

`testArray.find((item) => item.a === 3);` will result `Object { a: 3 }`
`tetArray.find((item) => item.a === 3);` will result `Uncaught ReferenceError: tetArray is not defined`
`notArray.find((item) => item.a === 3);` will result `Uncaught TypeError: notArray.find is not a function`
`testArray.find((item) => item.a === 7).a;` will result `Uncaught TypeError: testArray.find(...) is undefined`

Comment: That's why you're supposed to add a [mcve] that shows the behavior you're asking about... Or start debugging _before_ you ask on SO.

Comment: The real object is very complex, and also, I was overly confident in that `.find()` will always find a result in my situation.